# angularjs google-maps markers not showing on iPad/iPhone

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-markers, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I have the following HTML code:

```
<section data-ng-controller="NearbyController" ng-init="getUserLocation()">

  <!-- spinner while map is loading -->
  <span us-spinner spinner-key="spinner-1" spinner-start-active="true"></span>

  <div class="left-half-container">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">

      <!-- marker to show current user location -->
      <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" idkey="marker.id">
        <ui-gmap-window show="true" closeClick="closeClick()">
        </ui-gmap-window>
      </ui-gmap-marker>

      <ui-gmap-window ng-repeat="marker in allMarkers" show="marker.showWindow" options="marker.infoWindow" coords="marker.coords">
      </ui-gmap-window>
      <ui-gmap-markers models="allMarkers" coords="'coords'" options="'options'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClick'">
      </ui-gmap-markers>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>
  </div>
</section>
```

and here's the pertinent code from the controller (I think):

```
// pushing breweries data from $http request and place markers
var handleSuccess = function(data, status){
  if (data.data){
    $scope.breweries = data.data;
    placeMarker();
  }
  usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1'); //stop the spinner
};

var createMarker = function (i) {
  var name = $scope.breweries[i].brewery.name;
  var addr = ($scope.breweries[i].streetAddress !== undefined) ? $scope.breweries[i].streetAddress + '<br>' : '';
  var phone = ($scope.breweries[i].phone !== undefined) ? $scope.breweries[i].phone + '<br>' : '';
  var id = $scope.breweries[i].brewery.id;
  var dist = $scope.breweries[i].distance + ' miles away<br>';
  var desc = '<div class="info-window"><a href="#!/brewery/' + id + '"><strong>' +
             name + '</strong></a><br>' + dist + addr + phone + '</div>';
  var ret = {
    id: i,
    coords : {
      latitude: $scope.breweries[i].latitude,
      longitude: $scope.breweries[i].longitude,
    },
    options: {
      title: name,
    },
    infoWindow: {
      content: desc
    },
    icon: '/modules/nearby/images/beer-icon.png',
    showWindow: false
  };
  ret.onClick = function() {
    if ($scope.oldWindow > -1) {
      $scope.allMarkers[$scope.oldWindow].showWindow = false;
    }
    $scope.oldWindow = ret.id;
    ret.showWindow = !ret.showWindow;
  };

  return ret;
};

// create markers for all breweries
var placeMarker = function() { // places all the brewery markers
  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.breweries.length; i++) {
    markers.push(createMarker(i));
  }
  $scope.allMarkers = markers;
};

$scope.getUserLocation = function(){
    // function to access users geolocation coordinates, draw map and place markers
  geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
    $scope.coords = {lat:data.coords.latitude, long:data.coords.longitude};

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
      $scope.map = { center: { latitude: $scope.coords.lat, longitude: $scope.coords.long }, zoom: 12};
      $scope.windowOptions = {
        visible: true
      };

      curLocationMarker(); // add marker for current location
      Breweries.getData($scope.coords).success(handleSuccess); // get brewery data from factory
    });
  });
};
```

This all works fine on the following:  Windows desktop, Macbook Air, Windows phones and Android phones.  The problem is specifically with Safari browser on iPads and iPhones (Chrome browser on iPads and iPhones works!).  When you first go to the map, just the map displays and no current location marker or brewery markers.  If you go back and then forward again in the browser, you can get the current location marker to show, but still no brewery markers!

I've spent a couple of days on this now trying to solve it and I can't figure it out.  I run a Windows 7 setup, so I can't hook up to the safari browser using the Web Inspector and I've tried weinre to no avail.

You can see this for yourself on the live site:  ontappapp.azurewebsites.net and going to "Nearby" in the menu or "Discover Breweries Nearby".  Thanks!

Comment: So the markers are showing up in Safari on iPad now, but don't seem to be showing up on iPhone.  They do show when Safari is open on a Mac and the user agent is set to iPhone.  I'm really confused.....